# Failing to recover covariance parameters of random effects in a a linear mixed model simulation

Tags: mixed-model, estimation, simulation, random-effects-model

I am simulating data following this scenario: In a farm, the owner is interested in studying the effect of litter size on the weight at birth ($wb$) of some chickens. A random sample of litters (eggs laid by the same chicken) was selected and for all eggs at hatching wb was measured. The following model is assumed:

$$y_{i,j}= \beta_0+\beta_1 x_j+\gamma_{0,j}+\gamma_{1,j}x_j+\epsilon_{i,j}$$

where $y_{i,j}$ is the $wb$ of chicken $i$ at litter $j$, $x_j$ is the size of the litter $j$, $\gamma_{0,j}, \gamma_{1,j}$ are random effects, associated to litter $j$ and $\epsilon_{i,j}$ is the error term. We assume that $\gamma_{l,j} \perp \epsilon_{i,k}$, $\gamma_{l,j} \perp \gamma_{l',j'}$ ($l\neq l'$ and $j\neq j'$) and a general covariance matrix $\Sigma$ for $\gamma_{0,j}, \gamma_{1,j}$.

Next I present the code to simulate the data in R:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(MASS)
p_load(nlme)
p_load(mvtnorm)
set.seed(123)

#data simulation: litters, eggs inside litters
#number of litters
litter<-1:250
#simulate number of eggs per litter
litter_b<-rep(litter,sample(4:9,length(litter),replace = T))
#store in dataframe z0
z0<-data.frame(litter_id=factor(litter_b))
#calculate size of litter
z0<-z0 %>% group_by(litter_id) %>% mutate(size_l=n()) %>% data.frame()
#adding sex variable at the level of egg
z0$sex<-sample(c("F","M"),nrow(z0),replace =T,c(0.6,0.4)) %>% factor()

#design matrices for random and fixed effects
#random
Zl<-model.matrix(~-1+ litter_id+litter_id:size_l, z0)
Zl<-Zl[, order(colnames(Zl))]
#fixed
X<-model.matrix(~size_l, z0)

#random effects covariance matrix
DL_i<-matrix(c(0.07166667^2,0,0,0.1075^2),nrow = 2)
DL<-kronecker(diag(rep(1,length(unique(z0$litter_id)))),DL_i)
bL<-rmvnorm(1,rep(0,nrow(DL)),DL) %>% t

#error term e
sd_e<-0.31
e<-rnorm(nrow(z0),0,sd_e)

#fixed effects
my_bts<-c(26.7,-1.3)

#simulate bw
z0$bw<-(X%*%my_bts+Zl%*%bL+e) %>% drop

z0 %>% ggplot(aes(x=factor(size_l),y=bw))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image: bwvssize_l]

Now, let us estimate this model using package nlme:

```
#general covariance matrix for random effects
m0<-lme(bw~size_l,random = list(litter_id=pdSymm(~1+size_l)),data=z0)
intervals(m0)
Approximate 95% confidence intervals

 Fixed effects:
                lower      est.     upper
(Intercept) 26.418384 26.690633 26.962882
size_l      -1.342476 -1.295642 -1.248808

 Random Effects:
  Level: litter_id 
                              lower       est.     upper
sd((Intercept))          0.15212912  0.5945646 2.3237307
sd(size_l)               0.07293884  0.1455194 0.2903238
cor((Intercept),size_l) -0.96767316 -0.7451940 0.1295045

 Within-group standard error:
    lower      est.     upper 
0.3002598 0.3116566 0.3234860 

#diagonal covariance matrix for random effects
m01<-lme(bw~size_l,random = list(litter_id=pdDiag(~1+size_l)),data=z0)
intervals(m01)

Approximate 95% confidence intervals

 Fixed effects:
                lower      est.     upper
(Intercept) 26.426289 26.693047 26.959804
size_l      -1.342272 -1.296446 -1.250619

 Random Effects:
  Level: litter_id 
                       lower       est.        upper
sd((Intercept)) 1.736431e-42 0.00078525 3.551064e+35
sd(size_l)      9.282667e-02 0.10183503 1.117176e-01

 Within-group standard error:
    lower      est.     upper 
0.3002649 0.3116603 0.3234882
```

If we compare those estimated values with the values actually used for simulation (object `DL_i`) they are not very near each other, in particular, correlation between random effects was set to 0, but estimation of this (`m0` model) is far from 0 (although confidence interval contains the 0). Even increasing sample size for litters does not produce any improvement in the estimations of covariance matrix for the random effects.

I am wondering if there is any error in my simulation (to check correctness of `X`, `Zl`, `DL_i` and `DL` I just set `litter<-1:5` and visually inspect that all those matrices are indeed well specified). I also explored setting a non-zero covariance between the random effects (`DL_i<-matrix(c(0.07166667^2,0.003081667,0.003081667,0.1075^2),nrow = 2)`) with similar, inconsistent results.

I appreciate any thoughts on this. Is this behavior normal, in the sense to have such an inaccurate estimations for the covariance of the random effects? or there is some error in my code that is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some study of the parameters on the simulations and the scenario itself two things were noted:

1. Covariance matrix for random effects (object `DL_i`) has a determinant near zero `(5.935419e-05)`
2. Random effect associated to `size_l` (litter size) may have not much sense, since this is a variable at the level of litter and not at the level of egg.

item 2 is very important since we are assuming that the 'slope' can vary in each litter, but the fact is that conceptually the effect of the size litter on the birth weight can only be studied across different litters and not inside a given litter. The value of the litter size is constant in a given litter and thus it may have not much sense in assuming a random slope in each litter.

Finally, to test this out, first I changed the values of the covariance matrix to this:

```
sd_l0<-1.5
sd_l1<-0.7
cor01<-0.45
cov01<-sd_l0*sd_l1*cor01
DL_i<-matrix(c(sd_l0^2,cov01,cov01,sd_l1^2),nrow = 2)
```

I ran the simulations and observed the same behavior. Second I changed the model to this one:

$$y_{i,j}=\beta_0+\beta_1sex_{i,j}+\gamma_{0,j}+\gamma_{1,j}sex_{i,j}+\epsilon_{i,j}$$
This time a random effect is associated to a covariate at the level of the egg rather than the litter. Here is the code to do the simulation and fit the model:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(MASS)
p_load(nlme)
p_load(mvtnorm)
set.seed(123)

#data simulation: litters, eggs inside litters
#number of litters
litter<-1:250
litter_b<-rep(litter,sample(4:9,length(litter),replace = T))
z0<-data.frame(litter_id=factor(litter_b))
z0<-z0 %>% group_by(litter_id) %>% mutate(size_l=n()) %>% data.frame()
z0$sex<-sample(c("F","M"),nrow(z0),replace =T,c(0.6,0.4)) %>% factor()

#design matrices for random and fixed effects
Zl<-model.matrix(~-1+ litter_id+litter_id:sex, z0)
Zl<-Zl[, order(colnames(Zl))]
X<-model.matrix(~size_l+sex, z0)

#random effects covariance matrix
sd_l0<-1.5
sd_l1<-0.7
cor01<-0.45
cov01<-sd_l0*sd_l1*cor01
DL_i<-matrix(c(sd_l0^2,cov01,cov01,sd_l1^2),nrow = 2)
DL<-kronecker(diag(rep(1,length(unique(z0$litter_id)))),DL_i)
bL<-rmvnorm(1,rep(0,nrow(DL)),DL) %>% t
DL_i

#random effects e
sd_e<-0.31
e<-rnorm(nrow(z0),0,sd_e)

#fixed effects
my_bts<-c(26.7,-1.3,3)

#simulate bw
z0$bw<-(X%*%my_bts+Zl%*%bL+e) %>% drop

m0<-lme(bw~size_l+sex,random = list(litter_id=pdSymm(~1+sex)),data=z0)
intervals(m0)

Approximate 95% confidence intervals

 Fixed effects:
                lower      est.     upper
(Intercept) 26.490528 27.168679 27.846830
size_l      -1.466061 -1.366449 -1.266836
sexM         2.929500  3.017840  3.106180

 Random Effects:
  Level: litter_id 
                          lower      est.     upper
sd((Intercept))       1.3993980 1.5302698 1.6733807
sd(sexM)              0.5744386 0.6395807 0.7121101
cor((Intercept),sexM) 0.3428279 0.4636633 0.5694051

 Within-group standard error:
    lower      est.     upper 
0.2999548 0.3124722 0.3255120
```

This time parameters are recovered much better. Finally setting the original covariance matrix for this new simulation produced unstable results again.